# как получить значение строки по id в yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

ребят у меня есть таблица product в ней есть строка организация_id, при заполнении таблицы туда передается id организации,

а в таблице организации(organ) есть 2 строки name и id

```
<?=$product->organ_id?> этот код выводит айди заполненный в таблице product
```

и как мне получить имя(name) организациия(organ) обращаясь в таблицу product

Comment: Создайте реляцию в модели Product и через неё обращайтесь к организации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых тебе нужно связать модель product с моделью organ. Для этого в модели product нужно прописать метод

```
public function getOrgan()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Organ::className(), ['организация_id' => 'id']);
}
```

При создании в контроллере запроса к product

```
$product = Product::find()->with('organ')->all();
```

Все. Данные организации у тебя в объекте $product. var_dump($product) что бы увидеть где он там находится.

Comment: дело в том что я получил в     <?= DetailView::widget([
                        'model' => $product,
                        'attributes' => [
                            'organ.name',  ],
                    ]) ?> но как это получить без DetailView::widget

Comment: Ну так я и описал процедуру безо всякого DetailView. Создавай $product = Product::find()->with('organ')->all(); где угодно.

Comment: спасибо огромное решил)